# What is the word/phrase to uncamelcase something

Tags: naming-conventions, camelcasing

Ie. I have this "myFunction" to "my Function".

What is this called?

I'm not looking for a function to do this, but i'd like to know how to say it in conversation...

Comment: Probably belongs on http://english.stackexchange.com/ instead of here

Answer (score 0):

I would say, express the function name in normal english.

Answer (score 0):

Proper Case / sentence case as opposed to camel case.